# Reading a csv file and populating an array that holds objects from the file

Tags: java, arrays, string, exception

I am having a problem with my code below, when I run it after compiling it throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class DamArrayApp {

    int num = 0;
    ObjDam[] data = new ObjDam[211];

    public void populateArray() {
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("DamLevels.csv"));
            String firstLine = s.nextLine();
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                String all = s.nextLine();
                String[] temp = all.split(",");
                String name = temp[2];
                double fscNum = Double.parseDouble(temp[10]);
                double damlvl = Double.parseDouble(temp[25]);
                data[num] = new ObjDam(name, fscNum, damlvl);
                num++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File was not found. Please make sure the file exists!");

        }
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    public void printDam(String damName) {
        boolean find = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 211; i++) {
            ObjDam dam = data[i];
            if (dam.getDamName() == damName) {
                System.out.println("Dam Name: " + dam.getDamName()
                        + ", FSC: " + dam.getFsc()
                        + ", Dam Level: " + dam.getDamLevel());
                find = true;
            }
        }
        if (find == false) {
            System.out.println("The dam ___ you entered cannot be found in the file");
        }
    }

    public void printAllDams() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DamArrayApp run = new DamArrayApp();
        run.populateArray();
    }
}
```

I think the issue lies in the populateArray() method. Any ideas?
Note: the file contains extensive details about Dams and their water levels, all separated by commas.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that you probably want `while(s.hasNextLine())` instead of `while(s.hasNext())` .

Comment: That's a pretty specific error message. What about it don't you understand? The stack trace should even tell you the line number.

Comment: Worked it out now thanks. A bit new to Java but yeah you are right it did tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most probably thrown by Double.parseDouble method because the string you are trying to parse is empty.